# Correct declaring of a class in Dart

Tags: class, dart

I am new to dart and I have some basicaly question to the language itself.
During the last days I started with classes in dart.

Now I have a short question about how to declare a class correct.

```
  void main() {
  Book harryPotter =
      Book(title: "Goblet of Fire", author: "J. K. Rolling", pageCount: 300);

  print(harryPotter._title); // 1 -> print "A" to the console 
  print(harryPotter._author); // 2 -> LateInitializationError: Field '_author@18448617' has not been initialized.

}

class Book {
  String _title = "A";
  late String _author;
  late int _pageCount;

  Book(
      {required String title,
      required String author,
      required int pageCount}); // 3
}
```

1. Why can I access to the variable even if it's set to private?
2. Why does the late keyword throw an error, the variable is set during the constructor call?
3. Do I need to write in the constructor "Book({required String this.title});", or "Book({required String title});" like in the example? If it doesn't matter, why?

Thanks for helping!
Benjamin

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is not initializing the variables!

It should be:

```dart
  Book({required String title, required String author, required int pageCount})
      : _title = title,
        _author = author,
        _pageCount = pageCount;
```

Without that, the `_author` field is not set at all, and reading an unset late field is an error.

You can't use `this.something` because the fields have private names (`_author`) and named parameters *cannot* have private names. Otherwise that would have been the correct approach. Instead you need to have public-named parameters and then use the value to initialize the field in an initializer list.

With that change, the fields also don't need to be `late` and can instead be final:

```dart
class Book {
  final String _title;
  final String _author;
  final int _pageCount;

  Book({required String title, required String author, required int pageCount})
      : _title = title,
        _author = author,
        _pageCount = pageCount;
}
```

You can access the private variables from inside the same library because Dart privacy is *library* based.